# Unir 2 grupos de condiciones con el operador OR

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Quiero hacer una consulta con **eloquent** en **laravel**, el cual no se me ocurre como conseguirlo, con `where` y `orWhere`.

Quiero conseguir algo asi:

```
(var1 AND var2) OR (var3 AND var4).
```

Lo que he intentado hacer, mas que nada para unir estas 2 consultas y dejarlo en solo 1, con la condición `OR` entre las 2.

```
$valid1 = Schedule::where('day', $request->day)
                ->where('start_time', '>=', $request->starttime) // var1
                ->where('end_time', '<=', $request->endtime) // var2
                ->exists();
$valid2 = Schedule::where('day', $request->day)
                ->where('start_time', '<=', $request->starttime) // var3
                ->where('end_time', '>=', $request->endtime) // var4
                ->exists();
```

Comment: Pregunta editada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba de este modo:

```
$valid = Schedule::where([
            ['day', '=', $request->day],
            ['start_time', '>=', $request->starttime],
            ['end_time', '<=', $request->endtime]
        ])->orWhere([
            ['day', '=', $request->day],
            ['start_time', '<=', $request->starttime],
            ['end_time', '>=', $request->endtime]
        ])->get();
```

Lo que hice:

- Pase en forma de arrays dentro del primer `where()` varios con las primeras 3 condiciones a cumplir; estas 3 son las primeras que la consulta buscará cumplir.
- Encadenamos fuera del primer `where` ahora el método `orWhere()` y por dentro le pase 3 arrays con las siguientes 3 condiciones a cumplir; estas solo se comprobarán si las del primer método no son ciertas
- Devuelvo el resultado de la consulta con `get()`

Referencias:

- [Método `where()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)