# Como hago una consulta compuesta de operadores Lógicos AND Y OR en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Quiero hacer la siguiente consulta en laravel. Es un select con dos condiciones y el operador Logico OR. dentro de cada condición a su ves hay dos condiciones mas con el operador AND

```
SELECT * FROM sections 
WHERE (servicio_id='$id' AND empresa_id='$empresaID') 
OR (servicio_id='$id' AND lugar='Salons')
```

No he logrado usar el ORM para resolver esta consulta

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: $section = DB::select("SELECT * FROM sections WHERE (servicio_id='$id' AND empresa_id='$empresaID') OR (servicio_id='$id' AND lugar='Salons')"); La consulta funciona de echo. Pero pode los registros en un especie de objeto en el cual se ma hace imposible acceder a los datos

Comment: ¿Y si creas un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: @LuisCazares no es necesario ya que por medio de Eloquent se logra simple, el detalle al OP se le está haciendo cuesta arriba por no usarlo y escribir la consulta por medio del facade DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de funciones `callback`, son muy útiles al momento de realizar consultas mas amplias.

Suponiendo que ya tienes tu modelo `Section` definido, puedes hacer:

```
$dat = Section::where(function ($query) use ($id,$empresaID) {
                  $query->where('servicio_id', $id)
                        ->where('empresa_id', $empresaID);
                })
                ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($id) {
                  $query->where('servicio_id', $id)
                        ->where('lugar', 'Salons');
                })->get();
```

Donde cada función retorna una consulta, ademas aclarar que `use (param...)` sirve para pasarle `N` parámetros a la función.

Answer (score 0):

En tu consulta deberás tener el modelo `Section`que puedes crear desde la consola así:

```
php artisan make:model Section
```

El cual trabajaremos del modo siguiente para construir nuestra consulta

```
$dat = Section::where([
                        ['servicio_id', '=', $id],
                        ['empresa_id', '=', $empresaID]
                     ])->orWhere([
                        ['servicio_id', '=', $id],
                        ['lugar', '=', 'Salons']
                     ])->get();
```

Convierte a cada método `where` en una matriz donde pasas en fotmato de vector las dos condiciones a cumplir en cada uno de ellos.

La consulta anterior te devuelve una colección que será fácil de iterar por medio de un ciclo `foreach`

Igual aquí puedes [consultar otro ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/269682/unir-2-consultas-en-eloquent-con-el-operador-or/269685?r=SearchResults#269685)